# What command to get the width of POS printer?

Tags: command, thermal-printer

I have an application that prints to a thermal printer.  I was testing with a 52mm printer which was what the client said would be used and this is what I based my formatting on.

However, it turns out that there may be 80mm printers also.  Is there a POS command that will return the printing width of the connected printer?

Comment: Did you find the ESC/POS command for getting these values?